# Show that $f(x) = x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x$ is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

I want to show that the real polynomial function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x) = x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x$ is bijective. I want to show this *without* using the inverse or the derivative.

I'm struggling to prove injectivity, because I see no easy way to arrive at $x = y$. What I have so far:

**Surjective:**

Because the degree is odd, we have $\lim_{x \to +\infty}(f(x)) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}(f(x)) = -\infty$. Because a polynom is continuous, we can apply the IVT to the interval $I = (-\infty,+\infty) = \mathbb R$ so that for every $y \in I$ there is a $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.

**Injective:**

Let $f(x) = f(y)$. Then $x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x = y^7 + y^5 + y^3 + y$. Then ??? , so $x = y$.

Comment: The derivative is strictly positive so the function is strictly increasing.

Comment: $f$ is odd, therefore it is enough to deal with the case $x,y\geq 0$. If $0=f(x)-f(y)$ $=x^7-y^7+x^5-y^5+x^3-y^3+x-y=(x-y)(x^6+x^5y+x^4y^2+x^3y^3 + ...)$, where all the terms on the second factor are non-negative, and there is one that is a $1$. Therefore either $x-y=0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For injectivity: the sum of strictly increasing functions is strictly increasing. And $x^k$ is strictly increasing for odd $k$.

Comment: This is the best observation

Answer (score 1):

For injectivity we may use Descarte's rule of signs. Suppose we want solutions to $f(x)=c$. This is equivalent to showing the following has *exactly one root*: $$x^7+x^5+x^3+x-c=0$$ Suppose $c$ is positive (this works for $c<0$ but I'll leave that to you.

Now $f(x)-c=0$ has exactly one sign change, so there is exactly 1 positive root, or one positive solution to $f(x)=c$. To examine negative roots we look at $f(-x)-c=0$, which is 
$$
-x^7-x^5-x^3-x-c=0.
$$
This has no sign changes, hence no roots.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This is an odd function.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean it, but $\sin x$ is an odd function and it is not bijective or even injective.

Comment: @ajotatxe: Yes, but this function is clearly increasing for positive $x$ (unlike $\sin(x)$).

Comment: @paw88789 I would say it's clearly increasing for all $x$...

Comment: @paw88789 Ok, I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f(a)=f(b).$  Then since 
$$
f(x)=x \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{4}+1 \right) 
$$
we have 
$$
0=f(a)-f(b)={b}^{7}+{b}^{5}+{b}^{3}+b-({a}^{7}+{a}^{5}+{a}^{3}+a) = \left( b-a \right)  \left(  \left( b-a \right) ^{2}+1 \right) 
 \left(  \left( b-a \right) ^{4}+1 \right).
$$
Its implies that $a=b$, so $f$ is injective